# Delineating catchments upstream of flow sites

Tags: arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, watershed, arc-hydro

I have many flow sites and I used them to delineate catchments upstream of each flow site using Spatial Analyst Tools > Hydrology > Watershed.

As you know using this tool, you'll get the catchments delineated as shown below (Figure 1).

Is there a way to get the catchments delineated as illustrated in Figure 2? In other words, as you move downstream, the catchment of each flow site will include all the catchments upstream of this site.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple model. This question was asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/how-to-get-the-subbasin-area-of-each-specified-river-segment/82178#82178), for which I give a model showing how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ArcHydo http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/hydro/01vn00000010000000.htm it is a much more comprehensive toolset.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm using ArcHydro but I don't know which tool could delineate the catchments as illustrated in figure 2.