# How to get polyline features from a raster file using ArcGIS 10.1？

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, polyline-creation, line

I have a watershed accumulation file look like this：[image]

There are several **white lines** by visual, and I tried the **raster to polyline** tool and got this：
[image]

Are there better ways to extract polyline features from a raster file instead of creating an new shapefile and drawing lines by myself？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before you run the raster to polyline tool, you should set a threshold on your accumulation value in order to define the background to zero. This can be done in many ways, e.g.  using "reclassify" or using map algebra ( something like : Con( flowacc > threshold , 1, 0) ).

Alternatively, you can use "stream to feature", with a background set to NoData using SetNull( flowac > threshold, flowacc )

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to set thresholds to get the best resolution of the output line!

Comment: @Heinz Setting the threshold is what [Stream definition](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/how-to-get-the-subbasin-area-of-each-specified-river-segment/82137#82137) does, and the following functions will vectorize your flow paths.

Comment: @Martin I found that Arc Hydro Tools can't be installed in ArcGIS 10.1, or I miss something?

Comment: It sure does, but you tagged your question with 10.0 so I linked to that download. Log in to the ESRI ftp server and download the latest release for 10.1, as explained [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/26/are-you-using-arc-hydro-tools-for-10-1-beta/). Note however, the password on the linked site is outdated, check [forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/88-Arc-Hydro) for valid credentials.

Comment: @Martin now I'm downloading the latest beta file. As you said, all I need to do is what you said in my subbasin question, and it's no need to extract polyline from a raster file?

Comment: Well, those functions does what you need (including extracting polylines). So no, you don't need to find your own way of doing it. And yes, you need to do it but there's a function for that in the proposed workflow! :)