# How to identify the upstream sub basins contributing towards different drainage outlet points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arc-hydro

I have done the watershed delineation of a  basin and have created several sub-basins using ARC-hydro tool. 
Now I need to identify which are the correponding upstream sub-basins contributing towards a different drainage outlet point and find the total area of all sub-basins contributing towards a particular drainage point.
Is there any tool to perform this other than visual inspection because I have to deal with  a very large basin
[image]

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/how-to-get-the-subbasin-area-of-each-specified-river-segment